# Perl - Mojolicious Webpack Can't load application from file

Tags: perl, webpack, mojolicious

```
mojo webpack script\one_commex
```

Web application available at http://127.0.0.1:3000
Can't exec "C:\Users....\Box Sync\projects\perl_projects\mojo_projects\one_commex\node_modules.bin\webpack": No such file or directory at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/Webpack/Builder.pm line 214.
Can't load application from file "C:\Users....\Box Sync\projects\perl_projects\mojo_projects\one_commex\script\one_commex": [Webpack] exec C:\Users...\Box Sync\projects\perl_projects\mojo_projects\one_commex\node_modules.bin\webpack --config C:\Users...\Box Sync\projects\perl_projects\mojo_projects\one_commex\webpack.config.js --watch: No such file or directory at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/Webpack/Builder.pm line 215.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 107) line 1.
[Webpack] Could not find C:\Users...\Box Sync\projects\perl_projects\mojo_projects\one_commex\public\asset\webpack.development.html. Sure webpack has been run? at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/Webpack.pm line 87.

It works in Ubuntu machine correctly.
In windows, webpack installs the packages, creates assets directory, webpack.custom.js, creates a directory in public as "asset". But, it throws the error.

Comment: Content in :\Users\...\Box Sync\projects\perl_projects\mojo_projects\one_commex\node_modules\.bin\webpack

'''#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*|*MINGW*|*MSYS*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../webpack/bin/webpack.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/../webpack/bin/webpack.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
'''

Comment: It works in Ubuntu!

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to find the solution based on the trick that I learnt from setup done for my django project.

Manually created webpack.config.js for the common (development) settings and webpack.prod.config.js for the production along with package.json in the mojolicious project root directory

my webpack.config.js looks like below:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
var { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './public/javascripts/index',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./public/bundles/'),
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'jquery': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/src/jquery')
            }
        },
    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({
            filename: './webpack-stats.json'
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            jquery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            Highcharts: 'highcharts',
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: `[name].css`
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                        }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
                use: [
                        {
                                loader: 'url-loader',
                        }
                ],
            },
            { 
                test: /\.(sass|scss|css)?$/, 
                use: [
                        { 
                                loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                                options: {
                                        publicPath: './bundles',
                                }
                        },
                        { loader: 'css-loader' },
                        {
                                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                                options: {
                                plugins: function () { // post css plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
                                return [
                                    require('precss'),
                                    require('autoprefixer')
                                ];
                                }
                                }
                        },
                        { loader: 'resolve-url-loader' },
                        { loader: 'sass-loader' }
                ]

            }, 
            { 
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, 
                use: ['file-loader']
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

my layout template default.html.ep looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    %= include 'layouts/_mojo_default'
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/bundles/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= content %>
    <h1 class="text-primary">All OK!<h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then, added the following scripts in my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "build-watch": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode development --watch",
    "build-production": "webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js --mode production"
  },
```

So, now I can open one console for running the following which takes care of building packages as and when the front-end codes change

```
> npm run build-watch
```

In other console, I run the following:

```
> morbo script\<app>
```

Before deployment, I will run the following:

```
> npm run build-production
```

And change my default.html.ep (though dynamic way can be done with the help of server side operation)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    %= include 'layouts/_mojo_default'
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= content %>
    <h1 class="text-primary">All OK!<h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

That's it!

Comment: I think the above `default.html.ep` would be even better if you used the `mode` for a `development` "variant" to differentiate between dev and production (https://mojolicious.io/blog/2017/12/07/day-7-using-template-variants-for-a-beta-landing-page/), rather than changing the template.

Comment: @Ed thank you. Will do the same.